# How to stop Bluefish from displaying "File contains very long lines. Split these lines?" message

Tags: bluefish

This message is displayed when opening a file that contain not-too-long lines. Off course it displays when the file contains very long lines. But I want to stop this pop up message from showing up. I know it may affect the performance, but it just an extra click i wanna get rid of.

Comment: Someone else with the same problem on: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105253/how-do-i-remove-the-split-lines-error-in-bluefish. No answer has been provided as of yet but it might show up over there.

Comment: Apparently, the thing should be fixed in the 2.2.5 release of Bluefish - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720494#c3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This a copy of the answer that I posted on Unix & Linux regarding a similar question to this one, titled: [How do I remove the 'split lines' error in Bluefish?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105253/how-do-i-remove-the-split-lines-error-in-bluefish). I'm posting it here since the solution driven from the ticket I posted (referenced below) will likely lead to a potential solution for both.*

---

#### Similar sounding bug?

Not sure if this issue is related or not but if you look at the details of this issue in the Bluefish bugzilla issue tracker. The issue is titled: [Very long lines and cpu usage](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701628), which doesn't sound related but if you look through the question:

*excerpt*

> I've tested this with bluefish 2.2.2, built against gtk+-2.24.17 and later
>   against gtk+-3.4.4, I got the same behavior.
>
> I do a lot of css editing, and I found some time ago that base64 images where a
>   problem. And the bigger they were, the bigger the problem was as well.
>
> base64 images can result in very long lines, even small images, because bitmap
>   info has to be stored using a subset of ascii (or whatever). So it's not
>   strange that I end with lines with +10,000 columns, sometimes much longer.
>
> When I scroll down such a file, the very moment the offending line is about to
>   appear the editor freezes, and I can see gkrellm becoming mad about cpu usage.
>   I can open the same file in nano and scroll as I wish without even noticing a
>   cpu peak.
>
> When a CSS file is full of this stuff I just close bluefish and use whatever is
>   at hand instead.

One of the developers then made this comment:

> thanks for reporting, unfortunately this is a known bug in the gtk textview
>   widget.
>
> there is a bugreport for gtk somewhere in bugzilla, but it hasn't been fixed
>   for years. I'm surprised that the windows build doesn't have this problem, it
>   also uses gtk....

I realize the error you're seeing sounds different but these 2 issues seem linked to me. I  would suggest filing this as a bug and seeing what the developers

#### Opened issue regarding this

To try and help expedite this issue for you and the other OP on U&L I filed this as a bug in Bugzilla for the Bluefish project.

- [Bug 720494 - Disable message complaining about file containing very long lines?](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720494)

Feel free to comment on that, hopefully we'll hear something soon regarding this issue.

Comment: According to the issue I filed this is fixed in 2.2.5, at least you can disable it now: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720494#c3